# Summation with inner products: properties and rearrangement

Tags: summation, products, index-notation, summation-method

OPTION 1.

I have this expression,

$$\sum \limits_{l=1}^{L}a_l^2 + \sum \limits_{l<j}^{L}a_l^2 \frac{a_j}{a_l}$$

and I would like to take out $$\sum \limits_{l=1}^{L}a_l^2$$, as to obtain something like:

$$\sum \limits_{l=1}^{L}a_l^2 \left(1 + \sum \limits_{l<j}^{L}\frac{a_j}{a_l}\right)$$

Does it make sense? Do you have any suggestion?

OPTION 2.

Alternatively, the expression above can also be re-written in a different way:

$$\sum \limits_{l=1}^{L}a_l^2 + \sum \limits_{l\neq j}^{L}a_l^2 \frac{a_j}{a_l}$$

which should be equivalent to (following [Double summation index notation: $\Sigma_{i<j}$ versus $\Sigma_{i\neq j}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3901641/double-summation-index-notation-sigma-ij-versus-sigma-i-neq-j)):

$$\sum \limits_{l=1}^{L}a_l^2 + \sum \limits_{l=1}^{L}\sum \limits_{l\neq j}^{L}a_l^2 \frac{a_j}{a_l}$$

Because of the distributivity property of summations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation), such as:

$$\left(\sum \limits_{l=1}^{L}a_l^2\right) \left(\sum \limits_{l\neq j}^{L}\frac{a_j}{a_l}\right)=\sum \limits_{l=1}^{L}\sum \limits_{l\neq j}^{L}a_l^2 \frac{a_j}{a_l}$$

we could re-write the original expression as:

$$\sum \limits_{l=1}^{L}a_l^2 \left(1 + \sum \limits_{l\neq j}^{L}\frac{a_j}{a_l}\right)$$

Does it seem correct to you?

Comment: If you give us some additional context that might help. I would guess that neither claim is true, but I'm not sure without finding at least a counterexample

Comment: Ok, I will show you how i think it might be correct. But possibly I am wrong.

Comment: I just made an edit to the question, hoping to be a bit more clear.

Comment: If any of the values are 0 then this is not true. So you at least need some condition for this to be true

Comment: why is that? Could you provide a quick and simple example?

Comment: my mistake, I reviewed your Option 2, it looks correct!